# will live(production play store) app stop if i enabled Play integrity Api from Google Play console?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I want implement Play integrity in Android app but i have doubt i want to know if i am going to enable Google play integrity from play console will it any effect on already live app(play store production app).

Thanks,

->Want to just confirm that it will not effect in live app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your app will not be affected.

Your app (new version of your app) will request an assessment from Google Play using Integrity API.

Then Google Play will return a verdict.

Then you (your app or backend) will decide how to disable users that have unsigned versions.

[image]
[image source](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview)

Comment: Hi @user16930239 Thanks for your support i want to know if i am going to implement integrity using "using Google cloud console" then still need to enable from play console or it's only required from Google CLoud console?.

Answer (score 0):

I  am facing a weired behaviour, After turn on the Integrity protection, Then,  When No Internet, my app leads to play store screen shown sleeping Satellite. Thus App not Functioning. I have double checked internet connection and the method will not run when no internet connection. But these checks not working After turn on the Integrity protection. But, Before its working. I do not know the cause actually.